# Google Sheets using checkboxes IF/FILTERING/REGEXMATCH in data validation "please enter a valid range"

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I am using IF and checkboxes to make a sheet with a searchable data validation dropdown menu.
However, I'm getting the following error with my code.

[Data validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTZ36.png)

The code I used is below. Originally I thought that the issue might have been that the nested IF statements were not returning series' thus the many `ARRAYFORMULA` commands. I have tried this without the `ARRAYFORMULA` commands I have tried this using `IFS` instead of `IF`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(M17, 
        FILTER(Traits!H2:H34, ARRAYFORMULA( REGEXMATCH(Traits!K2:K34, "Offensive"))),
        ARRAYFORMULA(
            IF(N17, 
                FILTER(Traits!H2:H34, ARRAYFORMULA( REGEXMATCH(Traits!K2:K34, "Defensive"))),
                
                ARRAYFORMULA(
                    IF(O17,
                        FILTER(Traits!H2:H34, ARRAYFORMULA( REGEXMATCH(Traits!K2:K34, "Utility"))),
                        Traits!H2:H34
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )  
)
```

[See sheet configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ofmb.png)

The sheets all are correctly named and all series return a value.
Additionally when I run the code outside of the data validation tool it functions.

[Code Functioning Outside of Data Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0W1T.png)

[The traits sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhGgn.png)

Comment: What I can tell you is that you have the data validation type set to "List from a range." And a formula is not a range... it's a formula. Select "Custom formula is" instead. In addition, you only need *one* instance of `ArrayFormula` "wrapping" a formula on the outside; there is no need for multiple instances throughout. Beyond that, at a glance, your formula doesn't look correctly written for data validation, as I see no locked ranges where I'd expect them. That's as far as I can offer from static images. If you want more help, consider sharing a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. google sheets data validation does not support advanced formulae in the adjacent field when criteria is set to `list from a range`. use your formula in some helper column (that can be hidden) or helper sheet (that can be also hidden)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing. I used query in a helper column with portions of the query based off checkbox cells.